# Making text resize in two aligned labels in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, storyboard

I have two labels, side by side, like this:

```
|--15--labelA--8--longerLabelB--15--|
```

I want to make both of their font sizes equal to each other on all screen sizes (grow and shrink together), but I get an error that says that I need to set one of the labels' content hugging priority higher, or the content compression resistance priority higher which makes one of them have larger text size than the other...

I've tried using stackview. No luck.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Are you trying to get the font size of LabelA to match the resulting font size of "auto-shrunk" text of LabelB?

Comment: @DonMag yes....

Comment: OK - just to be clear... You want both labels to be the same width and height? So it would look like this - top row is original font size (24.0), middle row right-label auto-shrinks and left-label matches, bottom row left-label auto-shrinks and right label matches? https://imgur.com/a/7f1j5W6

Comment: same height, not same width..

Comment: OK - you'll have to be a bit more clear on what you want as an end result... Do you want the font size to auto-shrink? Or, if B word-wraps do you want A to grow in Height to match B's new height? And do you want fixed-widths? Or you want one label to stretch its width but not the other? Maybe add an image or two to show exactly what you're after...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make them equal size control-drag from any one to the other and select `Equal-Widths`

Or

as the error say head to any one you want and make it's `contentHuggingPriority` / `contenyCompresseionResistence` set to 1000

Comment: thank you for your answer, but both options are making one bigger than the other...  :(

Comment: the first option won't but may texts have different content

Comment: they have different content. one is longer, so if each label takes half the screen, then a long text will shrink to fit, while a short one will stay big.

Answer (score 0):

both labelA and longerLabelB has its' content size, Apple call it intrinsic size, and it will have effect on layout. pls consider two situations below (fake code):

```
let totalLength = 15 + contentSize(LabelA) + 8 + contentSize(LabelB) + 15 
if totalLength > containerSize.width {
   // which label should be shorter or compressed? LabelA or LabelB? 
   // answer: compress the one with lower compression resistance priority. 

   // compressed one would with content like: "xxxx....", truncated with "..." at last
} else { 
   // which label should be longer or hugging? LabelA or LabelB? 
   // answer: stretch the one with lower content hugging priority. 
}
```

so, you may set longerLabelB's content Hugging priority to some value lower than labelA.

if you also want LabelA's content not compressed like "xxxx...", set its'
compression **resistance** priority higher than longerLabelB

labelA should be the default one, longerLabelB's setting snapshot as below:

[image]

NOTE: actual value of these two priorities are not important, the key is the priority, or which one is higher or lower

Comment: thank you for answering, but playing with these priorities will shrink one label at the expense of the other... not getting same font size :(